# How do you debug a cronjob that's not working?

Tags: php, cron

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = 'Apache';
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'PHP';
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = '/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../misc/autoload.php');

define('WP_ADMIN', 1);

print_r("before");
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../public/wp-load.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../public/wp-includes/rewrite.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../public/wp-admin/includes/file.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../public/wp-admin/includes/misc.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../public/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
print_r("after");
```

Using some cronjobs in my wp site, and I need to run this block of code, but the code runs without any error, but the code just stops running before "after" gets printed. It's not outputting any error.

I get a warning:

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/alpha/version/ver/v4.3.11/cake.com/scripts/run-resource.php:2) in /home/alpha/version/ver/v4.3.11/cake.com/vendor/cakeauto/phplibs/hg/wordpress/Bootstrap.php on line 150

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

This bit of code doesn't seem to display any error.

Comment: You need to isolate which one of the includes stops execution by adding more debug prints. Once you find the file where execution stops, look into that file. You might want to add `define('WP_DEBUG', true)` so that WP knows to output debug.

Comment: and basically its php so php needs to be in front of the file